# how to validate number format based on the locale defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, localization, number-formatting

I have input text field (type = string) which should accept number as input but the number format should be validated based on the defined locale code.

```
var number = '2,110.168';
if locale is en-in, this should be valid
if locale is nl-nl, this is not a valid format as it should be 2.110,168
```

Comment: What version of Angular is this, are you using reactive forms and what have you tried?

Comment: Is the comma in 2,110.168 a requirement? Will there be a random amount of decimal places as well?

Comment: angular 6 , yes we are using reactive forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Number.toLocaleString()` which returns the "language-sensitive representation" of a number.

If your input is in a form, you can create a custom validator to validate its value.

Comment: but OP has a string and not a number. So what should they do? This really does not answer the question.

Comment: how could we validate the localString entered in the input